# SQL Server version of MYSQL insert into

Tags: mysql, sql-server, subquery

I have the following query running on a MySQL, but it fails when I run it on a SQL Server database.
How should it look to please SQL Server?

```
INSERT INTO first_table (pk, data)
VALUES ((SELECT value
           FROM second_table
          WHERE key = 'key'),
          'other-data');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO first_table (pk, data)
SELECT value, 'other-data'
FROM second_table
WHERE key = 'key'
```

Comment: I am suprised! 27 sec. and I got an answer (actually five).
You get the points though you forgot the semicolon ;-)

Comment: thanks though you dont need to use the semi colon in MS SQL... ;)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this

```
INSERT INTO first_table (pk, data) 
SELECT  value ,
        'other-data'
FROM    second_table 
WHERE key = 'key'
```

Have a look at [INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933206(SQL.80).aspx)

> Load data using the SELECT and EXECUTE
>   options

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO first_table (pk, data)
SELECT value, 'other-data'
FROM second_table
WHERE key = 'key'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO first_table (pk, data)
SELECT value, 'other-data'
FROM second_table
WHERE key = 'key';
```

Comment: Nope the semicolon isn't necessary, I'm just trying to get into the habit of always using one

Answer (score -1):

You could use a subquery to retrieve the PK:

```
INSERT INTO first_table (pk, data)
SELECT
    (SELECT value FROM second_table WHERE key = 'key')
,   'other-data'
```